# how to handle POST request with flask

Tags: python, http, flask, http-post

At first I should say that I searched a lot and think that there's no problem with the code but it doesn't work. I send a dict by post method in the local host through this code:

```
`<body>

<div class="middle">
    <form action="insert.py"    method="post" >
     <input  type="number" class="num"   name="temp"     placeholder="temperature" />
     <input  type="number" class="num"  name="hum"      placeholder="humidity"/>
     <input  type="submit" class="btn" name="insert"   value="send">
    </form>
</div>
</body>`
```

but I receive nothing in the insert.py file. nothing is shown on the screen. Can anyone say that what's wrong with the code? insert.py file is as follows:

```
`#!C:\Users\Edris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/POST', methods=['POST'])
def form():
    if request.method=="POST":
        temp = request.form.get('temp')
        print("insert OK")
        print(temp)`
```

I searched through lots of codes in the site and it seems that there would be no problem with the code. the first code gets two numbers from user and in the second file (insert.py) the entered numbers must be shown on the screen but it's not

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to post the form to some endpoint with `action`. Please pay attention to where you are posting **to**. `insert.py` is not a valid endpoint in your application, on the other hand `/POST` probably is.

```html
<form action="/POST" method="post">
...
```

Comment: I have two files uploaded on the server. a php file which contains the first part of the code with the action that sends data to a python file(second file which contains the second code block of the question above). I didn't understand why you said insert.py is not a valid endpoint. Can you explain more?

Comment: You need to get your terms straight. Endpoint is different than a python file. You can not send data to a python file. You can only post form data to endpoints.